iOS Flutter NFC: "The connection to service named com.apple.nfcd.service.corenfc was invalidated: - Sandbox restriction"
I already created flutter NFC feature using nfc manager package and runs smoothly on Android, but when I try to run it on iOS device I keep getting the error below:

[NFCHardwareManager areFeaturesSupported:outError:]:358 XPC Error: Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=4099 "The connection to service named com.apple.nfcd.service.corenfc was invalidated: failed at lookup with error 159 - Sandbox restriction." UserInfo={NSDebugDescription=The connection to service named com.apple.nfcd.service.corenfc was invalidated: failed at lookup with error 159 - Sandbox restriction.

I already implemented the iOS setup & permission based on the NFC manager documentation but I still cannot trigger the NFC.

AddNear Field Communication Tag Reader Session Formats Entitlements to my entitlements.

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>com.apple.developer.nfc.readersession.formats</key>
    <array>
        <string>TAG</string>
    </array>
</dict>
</plist>


Add NFCReaderUsageDescription, com.apple.developer.nfc.readersession.felica.systemcodes and com.apple.developer.nfc.readersession.iso7816.select-identifiers to my Info.plist.

<key>NFCReaderUsageDescription</key>
    <string>Our app use nfc usage to scan the nfc card to record the driver attendance. These can be configured in Settings.</string>
<key>com.apple.developer.nfc.readersession.felica.systemcodes</key>
<key>com.apple.developer.nfc.readersession.ios7816.select-identifiers</key>

Does anyone know how to set it up correctly?

Are you running your app on a real device?

Yes, I'm using iphone 13 (iOS 17.5.1) to test the app
